# webkit-animation on IE

Tags: html, css

I have created following glow effect for my image controls but it is not working on IE. How can i make it run on IE9? or any alternative?

```
@-webkit-keyframes redPulse {
from { background-color: #FF5959; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #FF5959; }
50% { background-color: #FD9FA2; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #FD9FA2; }
to { background-color: #FF5959; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #FF5959; }
}

.red{
-webkit-animation-name: redPulse;
-webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
width:200px;
padding-top:0px;
margin-top:0px;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's still not suported

> Internet Explorer does not yet support the @keyframes rule or the
>   animation property.
>
> Firefox requires the prefix -moz-, Chrome and Safari require the
>   prefix -webkit-, and Opera require the prefix -o-.

From: http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp

**upd**
maybe it's can help in your case with some jquery
http://placenamehere.com/article/384/css3boxshadowininternetexplorerblurshadow/

Comment: It should work on IE10 without any vendor prefix: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673530(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: -ms- prefix is not working ,i already googled and found that it is not supported but i am searching for alternative

Comment: maybe it's can help you http://placenamehere.com/article/384/css3boxshadowininternetexplorerblurshadow/

Comment: @bfavaretto - That it works in IE10 doesn't do anybody any good today.